# CSS and Tables. Void frame?

Tags: html, css

Is there a CSS equivalent of `frame=void`?, or will I have to add `frame=void` to all the future tables I make?:

```
<table border=1 rules=all frame=void>
```

I tried googling it, and I found no results.

Comment: Wtf is `FRAME=VOID` supposed to be?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/PR-html40-19990824/struct/tables.html#borders

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tekky/HknDE/1/

Comment: Isn’t that just the tables border? `border:0px;`

Comment: Well, just set the tables border to 0px. If you to have those inner borders, set those borders on tr and td.

Comment: @Kissaki, I did but that doesn't remove the outer borders of them.

Comment: I like the sound of RULES=ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old html presentational attributes are not a useful thing to use nowadays. I would discourage you from using any attributes on any elements in your body with the exceptions of class, id, data-* and things on input, audio, video or img.

To get the same effect, use

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style:hidden;
}
table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color:black;
}
```

As demoed here: http://jsfiddle.net/HknDE/35/

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to use html attribute for it. I'm trying to get something similar to this in css: http://jsfiddle.net/tekky/HknDE/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS the `border` property:

```
table { border:none; }
```

CSS rules will trump these old-school presentational HTML attributes. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <title>CSS and Tables. Void frame?</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border:none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>No Frame Attribute</h2>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>54</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>72</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>81</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>

    <h2>Frame = &quot;box&quot</h2>
    <table frame="box">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>54</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>72</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>81</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>

    <h2>Frame = &quot;void&quot</h2>
    <table frame="void">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>36</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>54</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>72</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>81</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>

</body>
</html>
```

... all three tables above render identically even though they have different values for the `frame` attribute.

Comment: That just gives no border what soever, I'm looking for a result similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/tekky/HknDE/1/

Answer (score -2):

Just set the tables border to 0px. If you want to have those inner borders, set those borders on `tr` and `td`.

```
table { border:0px; }
tr { border-bottom:1px; }
tr.last { border-bottom:0px; }
td { border-right:1px; }
td.last { border-right:0px; }
```

Or sth like that …